# How to use absolute imports in React Native

Tags: react-native

When trying to use absolute imports in React Native most suggestions point to using this library: [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver)

The issue is that this library has been archived and marked as read only by the creator. The last commit was in January. Therefore it would be unwise to use an unmaintained library.

I have also tried adding the following to my `tsconfig.json` as per other suggestions:

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
```

I think that possibly works in React, but not React Native which raises `unable to resolve module` when using absolute imports.

How should absolute paths be setup in a new React Native project (version 0.72.5) which uses typescript without using the above unmaintained library?

Answer (score -1):

You should configure **tsconfig.json** as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // other configurations,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

And in **babel.config.js**:

```json
{
  // other config here
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./src"],
        "extensions": [".ios.js", ".android.js", ".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".json"],
        "alias": {
          "@/*": ["./src"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Lastly, create a **package.json** file at the path: `src/package.json` with the following content:

```json
{
  "name": "@"
}
```

Comment: This appears to use `babel-plugin-module-resolver` which as stated in the original question has been archived and is unmaintained. Unmaintained libraries shouldn't be used. I am looking for a solution that does not use that plugin.